# Esri ArcGIS Imagery Labels too small?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm frequently working with the imagery basemaps provided by Esri.

I find that the labels (cities, districts etc.) are way too small.

Is there any option to increase the font size?

Comment: You'll need to access the imagery without labels, then generate your own -- https://geonet.esri.com/thread/62870

Comment: My project involves maping city structure types on a scale of 1:1.000 on an area of give or take 200 km², so doing all manually would just consume way too much time, with way too little use. Isn't there any way to make GIS display those automatically generated labels in a bigger font size? :/

Comment: Basemaps are *basemaps*. If you want to customize them, you have to do so locally.

Comment: @Vince I think your two comments would together make a quick answer.

Comment: Depending on what basemaps you are using, you might be able to do some work in QGIS using its Tile Map Scale Plugin and the Quick Map Services plugin with the More Services - Contributed Pack.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> You'll need to access the imagery without labels, then generate your
>   own -- [geonet.esri.com/thread/62870](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/62870)  ... Basemaps are *basemaps*.
>   If you want to customize them, you have to do so locally.

Alternatively you could submit an ArcGIS Idea for Esri to provide another basemap with a larger font - but for that to be implemented you would need lots of people to vote for it.